# WSDL with the same operation name and input type produce incorrect client stubs?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a WSDL file with the same operation name and request parameter name. When I generated the client stubs using the WSDL file, the port class produces a method with void return type. Furthermore, the request parameter changes from a single object to the contents of that single object.

Changing the operation name on the WSDL file to a different name works. However, I believe that modifying the WSDL file is a bad practice. Furthurmore, I have no access to the actual web service. As such I can't also change the actual operation name on the web service.

Is there a way such that `wsimport` won't be confused with the operation name and the request parameter name? I tried using the `-B-XautoNameResolution` attribute in wsimport but it didn't fix the problem.

My WSDL file looks like this: (As you can see, the operation name and request parameter name both uses the name 'transact')

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://com.example">
    <xsd:element name="transact">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="from" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="to" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>

<wsdl:message name="requestdata">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:transact" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="responsedata">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:responsedata" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="portname">
    <wsdl:operation name="transact">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:requestdata"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:responsedata"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

The resulting class is like this: (The return type is void and even though the input type is declared in the `RequestWrapper`, the declared methods inside the transact method is not the object itself.)

```
@WebMethod(action = "http://com.example/transact")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "transact", targetNamespace = "http://com.example", className = "com.example.Transact")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "transactresponse", targetNamespace = "http://com.example", className = "com.example.TransactResponse")
public void transact(
    @WebParam(name = "to", targetNamespace = "")
    String to,
    @WebParam(name = "from", targetNamespace = "")
    String from);
```

Comment: I don't see the definition of tns:responsedata in the WSDL file. Is there one? If so, could you also post it?

Comment: @Xargos: Thanks! I already updated my WSDL file to include the responsedata.

Comment: That WSDL still does not look right. element="tns:responsedata" does not point to any XSD element, hence the "void". If this is your WSDL, then the generated code is correct.

Comment: Hi, Xargos. I think you misunderstand my question. I know why the problem occured and it's because the operation name and the request parameter name are the same. I've included the WSDL just to show that the operation name and the request parameter name are the same which is the reason why I omitted most of the WSDL parts. Do you know a way to a way to generate in `wsimport` such that wsimport won't confuse the operation name from the request parameter name? Thanks!

Comment: So, the problem you have (if I understood correctly this time) is that instead of having Transact object as input parameter, you have String to, String from? If so it should still work. I have seen wsimport generating really weird code and work (e.g. Holder<String> as parameter instead of returning String). I might be having hard time getting what you mean, since what you posted seems correct to me. In general having operation name and the requestData element having the same name is not a problem, since nowhere in the protocol do they crash with each other.

Comment: @Xargos: Hi! Yes, instead of having Transact object as input parameter, I got String to and String from. Also, the return type became void. All of these happened because the operation name and request parameter name have the same names. I wonder if there's a way to make wsimport interpret the WSDL file correctly given the case above? I think by `Holder<String>` you mean `JAXBElement<String>`. If I'm not mistaken, it happens when your attribute is nillable. While some generated client stubs are still usable despite having some of those weird codes, it makes using them more inconvenient to use.

Comment: No, I mean Holder<String>. It is used for arguments that are returned, but thats off topic. In general no, you can't make it generate different code without changing the WSDL or XSD Schema. For all intents and purposes generated code is correct. You could, if you want to, edit it manually but be careful not to break it. Your return type is void because element="tns:responsedata" does not point to any XSD structure (as I mentioned before).

Comment: @Xargos: Yes, but I know there are wsimport attributes like `-B-XautoNameResolution` which can handle name conflicts automatically. Unfortunately, it seems that it is only limited to handle request parameter name conflicts so I'm wondering if there are other attributes like that that can handle my problem. `tns:responsedata` points to an XSD structure. I just didn't include it in the code above because I know that it's not the cause why the return type became void.

Answer (score 0):

This application is working as it should.
What you have done is Wrapper Style of Parameter Handling.
The Other style is bare style(Single Part arguement results in 1 java Object)

When Element Name of single-Part of Input Message is same as Operation name, It produces Multiple Parameters in unmarshalling of SOAP request to Java, instead of 1 Encapsulated Java Object.
This is known as "Wrapper Style" of parameter Handling.

```
<wsdl:part element="tns:transact" name="parameters"/>
<wsdl:operation name="transact">
```

WSDL Binding Type still remains "Document Style" as we are using single-part (Complex type in XSD)

Refer URLS:
https://myarch.com/wrappernon-wrapper-web-service-styles-things-you-need-to-know/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-usagewsdl/

Solution would be to change following 2 XML entries

```
<xsd:element name="transactNew">
<wsdl:part element="tns:transactNew" name="parameters"/>
```

Changing **transact** to **transactNew** will make it different from OperationName(transact) thereby solving the issue as Operation Name and Single Arguement Name are now different.